# Problem accessing admin zone drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I recently install a drupal for the first time.
Up to now all was pretty good.
But now i can't go on the admin zone.
When I want to go on any section I have a link to Dashboard display on each page.

Moreover when i want to logout I've an Internal Server Error

Have you an idea to resolve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what problem you have, if you are logged out and do not have a login block, you can go to /?q=user or /user and then go to /?q=admin or /admin. If this is not the problem, in general with these kind of issue you can try the following:

1. Disable any themes you might have activated ([drupalroot]/sites/all/themes/). Just rename the directory of the theme (mv yourtheme/ yourdisabledtheme/) and see if that solves things.
2. Disable the .htaccess file in the root of your Drupal install (it's hidden, so you need to do an ls -la to see it) by renaming it (mv .htaccess .htaccessdisabled) and see if this enables you to get into admin.

of course, rename them back afterwards. Good luck!